# Is there a "all" or "any" operator for boolean lists in typescript

Tags: typescript, boolean-operations

I want to write an if statement of the form

`if (all entries in booleanList are true) {do something}`

Just putting in the booleanList does the equivalent of .any()

I could not find an answer on the internet or in a typescript book. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's `every`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

```
const list = [true, false, true];

const every = list.every(bool => bool === true); // false
// const every = list.every(bool => bool); // false
```

Comment: thank you I'm going to accept @kaya3 answer since he was the fastest.

Comment: @kaya3 was actually the slowest :D

Comment: for me it says 13 for him and 12 for the other 2

Answer (score 10):

Typescript compiles to Javascript, so it doesn't have any features available at runtime that Javascript doesn't have. However, Javascript does have both [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) since ES5, so long as you pass an identity function:

```js
arr.every(x => x) // all
arr.some(x => x)  // any
```

This kind of thing is unlikely to be documented in Typescript books specifically, because there would be no need to duplicate the contents of a Javascript book just to say that Typescript has those features too. If you want to know what functions are available in the standard library, you should consult a Javascript reference, such as the [MDN Javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function for that:

```
if(booleanList.every(val => val)){
 do something
}
```

Comment: thank you I'm going to accept @kaya3 answer since he was the fastest.

Comment: if by fastest, you mean answered last, sure, but that's not what that word means.  have my upvote, on account of being fasted.